Comparing values in a matrix
Output table
I have the attached table. The data is produced as a matrix. I want to colour code the values under TP1, TP2, TP3 against the Baseline Value but can't for the life of me work out how to do it. Basically one colour for greater, one for the same and one for less.
Many thanks
Kevin
Not quite sure where to start with it. I know how to do it in a table but not a matrix.

Show a sample of the data from your dataset query, also show the expressions used in your matrix so we understand what you have built so far. It's should be simple but there's not enough info at the moment.
